# Docker: copy data from host to mounted host directory to access it from the running container

Tags: docker, storage, docker-volume

I have a running container with a volume mounted to a local host directory:

```
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Source": "/var/lib/postgresql-9.5-docker",
            "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
```

If I want to provide data from the host to the container (e.g., a big postgres dump), is it safe to directly write the file from the host to the host directory

```
/var/lib/postgresql-9.5-docker/foo/
```

?

A quick test shows that this is working (i.e., the file is there if I exec bash into the container and check), but is it safe for data consistency?

**Note:**

I know that one could use also

```
docker cp /path/to/src <containerid>:/path/to/dest
```

But in my specific case this doesn't work when the volume is mounted from Ceph (rbd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying files to a host directory will be as consistent via docker as you expect the host file system to be. There is a very thin layer between container and host.

Using [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) via the default `local` driver will also provide similar access as these volumes also use the local host filesystem.

Copying files into a docker containers file system will depend on the [storage driver you run docker with](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/). By default this is AUFS (soon to become OverlayFS) so there is an additional layer there over the standard file system. I wouldn't expect that to be less consistent but due to the extra layer there is more chance for an issue or bugs and it won't perform as well as your local file system either.

#### Access from both host and container

One feature you get from containers is shared information between the host and container. Everything that you do in the container is actually occurring in the hosts kernel. So if you write lock a file, the host can see that. If you have a file `mmap`ed then it will share the hosts global `mmap` space.

Accessing or writing to the same file system from both container and host is fine. You won't have differences or delays between the two.

Multiple processes writing to the same file or file location will have the same constraints as any multi process system. The processes would need to use file locking or a mutex otherwise writes could be interleaved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, if I understand, writing to the host directory should be even safer than actually writing through Docker as I don't have the additional AUFS layer? But the host filesystem and the AUFS layer won't come up with inconsistencies if at the same time both the Docker container (through AUFS) and the host are writing data to the same target?

Comment: Yep, a host directory has less overhead. That doesn't mean writing in a docker container is particularly "unsafe" though! I've added a section to the answer about consistancy.